# Calculate moment of inerta of cylinder along central diameter using inertia tensor

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals, physics, cylindrical-coordinates

[image]

how do I find the moment of inerta of cylinder along central diameter which is the one that is $(h^2 + 3r^2)M /12$ ???

I used triple integral and I get

[image]

Which I I'm not sure what I done wrong..Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By definition of moment of inertia $I_{xx}$,

$$
I_{xx} = \int (y^2+z^2) dm = \int (r^2 \sin^2 \theta +z^2) \frac{M}{V} dV = \frac{M}{V}  \int_{-H/2}^{H/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^R (r^2 \sin^2 \theta +z^2) r dr d\theta dz
$$
what you doing wrong is that the limit of integration that you choose for $dz$ and the factor $\frac{M}{V}$. The integration on $z$ must run from $-H/2$ to $H/2$ by symmetry. And by substitute $V = \pi R^2 H$, you'll have the desired result.

Comment: hi @Sou thanks for helping

Comment: but @Sou I'm a little bit confused I mean for the moment of inertia along central axis instead of central diameter, do I still use the same triple definite integral also?

Comment: oh wait, I actually still calculating from centre of cylinder so it should be still -H/2 to H/2 if I'm not wrong??

Comment: @john : Yes. Whatever components of I that you want to calculate that involve z, it should be from -H/2 to H/2.